# GAE and django same users

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm running a GAE and Django helper project and i ran into some issues when creating a User from de django shell. After exploring the code under the helper directory i came across with the following code:

```
class User(BaseModel):  
      user = db.UserProperty(required=True)
```

My question is, do i have to bind the django user to a google account if so, how do i create a django or google user from my code?

UPDATE: I meant to say create the account without having the google account itself. For instace not having:

```
users.get_current_user()
```

UPDATE: A user must be able to create a new account just like regular django users, with a register page for that matter.

Comment: Do you require your application to use Google Account for authentification?

Comment: Any authentification, a user must be able to create a new account just like regular django users, with a register page for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

For AppEngine, you can get the users who are logged into your application.

```
from google.appengine.api import users
```

And then you do

```
username = users.get_current_user()
```

And set your user property

```
User(user=username)
```

You could lookup the tutorial on how to do redirect to login to ask the application to login to get the user.